# Check if int from textbox is empty + cast

Tags: c#, validation

I have the following form:

[image]

My field Quantity should be an int but I want to implement error checking.

This is my code:

```
   private void btn_Create_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            bool exit = false;

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tb_Quantity.Text))
            {
                lbl_Error.Visible = true;
                lbl_Error.Text = "Check required values !";
                exit = true;
            }

            int Quantity = int.Parse(tb_Quantity.Text.Trim());


            if (!exit)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ready to be created!");
            }

        }
```

The error that I get if my quantity is empty:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: use `TryParse` instead of `Parse`.

Comment: WinForms is what i'm using

Comment: are you sure you are passing `number` like this `"12"`

Answer (score 2):

Instead use `TryParse()` like below which won't throw exception in-case the casting fails (if it's NaN)

```
int.TryParse(tb_Quantity.Text.Trim(), out int quantity);
```